# The specified module 'C:\CloudDeployment\ECEngine\EnterpriseCloudEngine.psm1' was not loaded

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-stack

While registering with AzureStack, I encountered this error:

> The specified module 'C:\CloudDeployment\ECEngine\EnterpriseCloudEngine.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

I have checked the directories and there is no `C:\CloudDeployment\` directory.

Does anyone have any clue about this or where to get the above directory and PowerShell scripts in it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the Tools for using Azure Stack, these are listed in the projects [Github Readme](https://github.com/Azure/AzureStack-Tools/blob/master/README.md):

> To use these tools, obtain Azure Stack compatible Azure PowerShell
>   module. Unless you've installed from other sources, one way to do it
>   is to obtain from public package repositories as follows. Note that
>   both of these could still be used to operate against Azure as well as
>   Azure Stack, but may lack some of the latest Azure features.
>
> For PowerShell, install the following:
>
> ```
> Install-Module -Name 'AzureRm.Bootstrapper' -Scope CurrentUser
> Install-AzureRmProfile -profile '2017-03-09-profile' -Force -Scope CurrentUser
> Install-Module -Name AzureStack -RequiredVersion 1.2.9 -Scope CurrentUser
> ```
>
> Obtain the tools by cloning the git repository.
>
> ```
> git clone https://github.com/Azure/AzureStack-Tools.git --recursive
> cd AzureStack-Tools
> ```
>
> Otherwise download the tools as follows:
>
> ```
> invoke-webrequest https://github.com/Azure/AzureStack-Tools/archive/master.zip -OutFile master.zip
> expand-archive master.zip -DestinationPath . -Force
> cd AzureStack-Tools-master
> ```